# Microsoft Graph API getSchedule all-day events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to create a vacation leave calendar for my team using the Microsoft Graph API. I have successfully used the /me/calendar/getSchedule endpoint as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule.

However, the response does not include *all-day events.* Most people book leave for multiple days at a time. I would expect to see "oof" events (status 3) for whole 24 hour periods, but instead there are none.

Is there an option I am missing or another API that can provide this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but according to [the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule#example), it required you to set start time and end time parameters. I just want to confirm if you set the time range?

Comment: I have the time range set to a month, and I made sure I have a colleague who took leave in the chosen period.

Comment: I found another colleague whose leave does show in the schedule, and I see the full-day/multi-day events. It seems that there must be more than one way to represent leave in Microsoft Teams/Outlook, which doesn't show up in getSchedule.